# Python не видит библиотеки

Tags: python, ubuntu, консоль

Недавно установил убунту и столкнулся с вот такой проблемой : python не видит пакеты котроые я устанавливаю.
Устанавливаю пакеты через терминал ,использую вот эту команду

```sh
$ sudo apt-get install python-pygame
Уже установлен пакет python-pygame самой новой версии (1.9.6+dfsg-2build1).

Следующий пакет устанавливался автоматически и больше не требуется:
  python-is-python2

Для его удаления используйте «sudo apt autoremove».
Обновлено 0 пакетов, установлено 0 новых пакетов, для удаления отмечено 0 пакетов, и 221 пакетов не обновлено.
```

При попытке использования библиотерки выдаёт " No module named 'pygame'

Answer (score 1):

В тексте ответа вы можете увидеть точное название пакета: `python-is-python2`, то есть, скорее всего под названием устанавливаемого пакета `python-pygame` вы пытаетесь установить пакет для python 2.7.

Подозреваю, что вы хотите установить версию для python 3.+. В этом случае вам нужно искать пакет с названием `python3-pygame`.

А еще лучше, используйте штатный пакетный менеджер pip. Устанавливается он следующей командой:

```sh
$ sudo apt install python3-pip
```

Если такой библиотеки нет или возникают какие-либо конфликты, то можно использовать модуль-установщик `get-pip.py`

```sh
$ curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
$ python3 get-pip.py
```

Установка библиотеки:

```sh
$ pip3 install pygame
```